# Assignment operator overload not getting called

Tags: c++, overloading, copy-constructor, equivalent

I have two classes, Database and Record.

```
class Database {
    private:
        Record* head;
    public:
        Database(Record*);
        Database();
        Database(const Database&);

        Database& operator= (const Database &data);
};

class Record {
    public:
        Record(std::string, std::string, int, int, std::string);
        Record(const Record&);
        Record();

        Record* next;
};
```

Now when I do this

```
Database PM1, PM2;
//operations on PM1
PM2 = PM1;
```

All that happens is the values in PM1 are assigned to PM2. The assignment overload is never called. I have no idea as to why this may be happening. I've attempted to debug as well, but the function is just never entered. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the overload function, it may not be right, but I haven't been able to test it yet because I can't even get it to run.

```
Database& Database::operator= (const Database &data) {
    if(this == &data)
        return *this;
    if(data.head == NULL) {
        this->head = NULL;
        return *this;
    }
    Record *curr1, *curr2;
    curr1 = new Record(*(data.head));
    this->head = curr1;
    for(curr2 = data.head->next; curr1 != NULL && curr2 != NULL; curr1 = curr1->next) {
        curr1->next = new Record(*curr2);
        curr2 = curr2->next;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that your assignment operator is never called?

Comment: Aren't you debugging a release build?

Comment: The code looks right, if it is really as it is shown in here. I would try to clean and rebuild the program. Also add a log/break point just before the assignment, another log inside the assignment operator and run to see if it hits that line. It might be that the line with the assignment is never reached!

Comment: Yeah, it gets right to the line with the assignment, I step through and it just continues. Never enters the overload. I've got a breakpoint inside the overload as well, and it never stops at it. I've been thinking about this for quite awhile, and I don't know what to do, short of posting all of my ugly code on github or something. That just seems so unnecessary for what should be such a simple fix.

Comment: Seems correct to me. Can you write the body of assignment operator overload function?

Comment: Updated first post with the requested code.

Comment: I can only imagine that you actually have Database PM2 = PM1; in your code and you are calling copy constructor and not copy assignment. BTW you have memory leak in your assignment (you are not deleting this->head before assigning to it).

Comment: Yeah I see that memory leak is there, I just haven't gotten around to it, as I'm still trying to get that to work. What do you mean about copy constructor vs copy assignment?

EDIT: Just looked it up. I should be calling assignment, as both objects are initialized beforehand.

Comment: @mrobinson7627 true that,  I would be pretty impressed (and a little concerned) if the optimizer were cutting out a middle man and not even *initializing* PM2 until it is actually needed, then construct-initializing it. I know you tried to single-step it. Have you tried -O0 -g while doing so? Also, just to "know" the assignment operator is actually "The One" being called, try *hiding* the copy-ctor as private (at least as a test). This really is an interesting problem, as I'm leaning more toward something in the code we're *not* seeing rather than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you have pointer in your Database class and I guess you did not handle that you think you overloaded operator dose not work.
You do shallow copy. so you need to handle that!

Comment: So if there's a pointer in the class it just does a shallow copy? How do I make it go to the overload? I have the pointer handled in the overload, so it's not like I'm just setting pointers equal and then getting the same reference. Is there something specific I'm supposed to do to handle pointers?

Comment: Look this page you will find all. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/

Comment: @mrobinson7627 Your code looks right. I have no idea what this answer is trying to tell you, but it may do the author well to read the question and the posted code. Your override of the assignment operator  and copy constructor are exactly what you're supposed to do to handle dynamic members and comply with the Rule of Three (though you seem to be missing the virtual destructors that clean those members, but thats another issue). Something else must be wrong, because you appear to be doing this right.

Answer (score 0):

The objects may need to have been previously instantiated in order for the copy assignment function to be called.

```
// So instead of doing this:
Database PM1, PM2;
PM2 = PM1;

// Try this:
Database *PM1 = new Database();
Database *PM2 = new Database();
*PM2 = *PM1;
```